# Call functions when jQuery ajax is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I want to call my function loadTest() after bootstrap dialogs is loaded and shown.

```
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: {
            html: '',
            delay: 0.1
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('body').append('<div id="test_modal_wrapper"></div>');
            $('#test_modal_wrapper').html(data);
            $("#modal").modal({backdrop: 'static'});

            $('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
                $('#test_modal_wrapper').remove();
            });
            loadTest(1, 3);
            loadTest(2, 2);
            loadTest(3, 1);
        }
    });
});

function loadTest(id, delay) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/echo/html/',
        async: false,
        data: {
            html: '<div class="test-case"><h5>Testing connection '+ id +'</h5></div>',
            delay: delay
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.modal-body').append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is that dialog waits for all calls loadTest() to finish and then show dialog with results of loadTest() functions.

What I want is that dialog is first loaded, then loadTest() do it's magic. :)

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/matox/g1e8ray4)

Comment: Try removing `async:false`

Comment: Why do you use the same `url` for all AJAX requests? Is `'/echo/html/'` actual URL or placeholder?

Comment: URL is different for each function call.

Comment: i think loadTest() loaded after dialog. i see fiddle and working as per you need. now what is the prob?

Comment: @adeneo, I want to be function calls loaded in order

Comment: why did I recieve -1? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to postpone `loadTest` until modal has opened, use the `shown.bs.modal` event:

```
 $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        loadTest(1, 3);
        loadTest(2, 2);
        loadTest(3, 1);
 });
```